# What is the plural for magnetic moments/momenta?

Tags: etymology

I’m not sure what the origin of “moment” as in “moment of inertia” or “magnetic moment” is, or if they are even the same. Do they come from angular momentum?  If so, should the plural be “magnetic momenta”?

I often see “magnetic moments”, but I don’t have much reason to believe this is correct, as it is usually by people for whom English is not their area of expertise, and who make all sorts of other errors.

I’m curious, let me know?

Thanks

Comment: I'm accustomed to seeing "momenta" as the plural of "momentum" but "moments" as the plural of "moment".

Comment: To clarify, do you mean “moment” as in a “moment in time”, or as in the sense of torque?  This question could easily be extended to the word for torque, ie is that etymologically related to “momentum”? As I am fairly sure that magnetic moment is related to “moment” in the torque sense, though I could find no source for this.

Comment: I meant "moment" as in "magnetic moment", "moment of inertia", and "dipole moment".

Comment: Sort of an obvious place to look, but, since you haven't mentioned it in your post: as far as the etymology and history of these terms, have you looked [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(physics)#History)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plural of "moment" is definitely "moments," in all senses.

There are only two plausible reasons why the plural of "moment" might possibly be anything other than "moments," and neither reason holds up:

1. A handful of native English words have irregular plurals inherited from centuries ago, such as *mouse* (*mice*) and *goose* (*geese*). However, "moment" is not one of those words.
2. When we borrow a noun from another language into English, we often borrow both the singular and the plural from the original language. However, there is no possible origin language where the singular is "moment" and the plural is something other than "moment," so this situation can't have happened either.

Also, I checked a couple of dictionaries and all of them list "moments" as the only plural form of "moment."

---

This is a bit of a digression, but I'm guessing that there are no nouns at all in English where

- the English plural form is borrowed from some other language, but
- the English singular form is not the singular form from that other language, and
- the English singular form is not a backformation from the plural form, either. (An example of such a backformation is "tamale," which is back-formed from the English plural, "tamales," which is borrowed from the Spanish plural. The Spanish singular is *tamal*.)

If the plural of "moment" were "momenta," then it would be a counterexample to my guess.

Comment: So there is no relation between moment (in the sense of change in angular momentum) and momentum?  Or at least, if there is, it probably doesn't matter?

Comment: There is a relationship, and the relationship doesn't matter. When we discarded the original singular ending (*-um*), we discarded the original plural ending (*-a*) too.

Comment: Lots of words derive from Latin, but very few of them have Latinate plurals. If you don't do it for action, ratio, temple, or second, why would you do it for moment?